# Hibernate - One to many relationship and orphanRemoval cascade

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, cascade, orphan

I have a basic one to many relation parent / child like in the chapter 21 of Hibernate references book.
The cascade is only from child to parent (persist cascade only because I don't want to delete the parent if I delete a child).
When I add a child to the parent and I save the child, I have a TransientObjectException...

```
@Entity
public class Parent implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<Child> childs;

  public List<Child> getChilds() {
    return childs;
  }

  public void setChilds(List<Child> childs) {
    this.childs = childs;
  }

  public void addChild(Child child) {
    if (childs == null) childs = new ArrayList<Child>();
    if (childs.add(child)) child.setParent(this);
  }

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}

@Entity
public class Child implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  @Cascade( { PERSIST, MERGE, REFRESH, SAVE_UPDATE, REPLICATE, LOCK, DETACH })
  private Parent parent;

  public Parent getParent() {
    return parent;
  }

  public void setParent(Parent parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
  }

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}


@Test
public void test() {
  Parent parent = new Parent();
  Child child = new Child();
  parent.addChild(child);
  genericDao.saveOrUpdate(child);
}
```

But on the saveOrUpdate, I have this exception:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: Child
  at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:244)
  at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.getOrphans(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:911)
  at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag.getOrphans(PersistentBag.java:143)
  at org.hibernate.engine.CollectionEntry.getOrphans(CollectionEntry.java:373)
  at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.deleteOrphans(Cascade.java:471)
  at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:455)
  at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:362)
  at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:338)
  at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
  at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161)
  at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:476)
  at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:354)
  at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
  at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:130)
  at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
  at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
  at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:117)
  at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
  at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:677)
  at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:669)
  at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:252)
  at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392)
  at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335)
  at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
  at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161)
  at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:451)
  at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
  at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
  at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:130)
  at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
  at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
  at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:117)
  at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
  at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:677)
  at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:669)
  at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:665)
```

I really don't understand because saving the Child should save the Parent via the cascade...
Any ideas ?

**UPDATE 1**
The problem seems to be related to "orphanRemoval" because if I comment it on the parent:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent" /*, orphanRemoval = true */)
private List<Child> childs;
```

It works!
It save the child, then the parent.
But I really need the orphan to be deleted via the cascade when I remove a child from its parent.

**UPDATE 2**
I've created a JIRA issue:
http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5364

**UPDATE 3**
It seems to be fixed :-)
http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2269

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Use the button with zeros and ones to properly format your code in the future(I formatted it for you).

Comment: Thanks... we did it at the same time ;-)

Comment: What happens if you save the parent before saving the child?

Comment: It works but I cannot do that in my application. The children are used in other entities and saved by cascades... 
That's why I'd like to save also their parent when children are saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was an issue in Hibernate and it is now fixed:

http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2269

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are violating a constraint. The row in the db that corresponds to the parent doesn't exist, so there is no foreign key relationship that the child can use to refer to the parent. Add a call to saveOrUpdate on the parent before doing do for the child.

(edit) I missed your comment about cascade before the reformatting. My recollection is that cascade doesn't work upstream that way; you would still need to save the parent first.

Comment: OK but the saveOrUpdate in executed in a single transaction, so it first save the child, then the cascade should create the parent (and update the child foreign key) and finally flush to DB and only at this moment the constraints are validated... no ?

Comment: have you tried adding 'inverse=true' to the parent mapping? I wouldn't think that would work but Hibernate surprises me.

Comment: I'm not using xml configuration but annotations.
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent") does the same.

Comment: It seems that my problem comes from orphanRemoval... I've just updated my post.

Comment: @Cedric: Looks like a bug in Hibernate.

Comment: I've opened a JIRA issue: http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5364