# hibernate 3.6.7 orphanRemoval cascade unidirectional

Tags: java, hibernate

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "FacilityId", referencedColumnName = "Id")
@ForeignKey(name = "FK_Schedule_Facility")
@Cascade(value = {org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
@OrderBy("fromDay asc")
private Set<Schedule> schedules = new HashSet<Schedule>();
```

I have this set in Entity `Location`.

In my application I construct a new set using AJAX. This has not given me any problems. I can change values in Schedules, even add more. But I CANNOT delete one. It stays in the database and in the set.

I use this method in my DAO: 
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

```
public Facility saveOrUpdate(Facility facility){
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(facility);
    return facility;
}
```

So I'm getting this in the log:

```
2013-08-06 17:44:43,444 [1219450701@qtp-169872652-2] DEBUG com.firstbankpr.os.common.data.dao.hibernate.FacilityHibernateDAO - Obtaining Session
2013-08-06 17:44:43,450 [1219450701@qtp-169872652-2] WARN  org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 515, SQLState: 23000
2013-08-06 17:44:43,450 [1219450701@qtp-169872652-2] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'FacilityId', table 'OLS.dbo.Schedule'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
```

**After entering `nullable = false` in the `joinColumn` annotation, the error goes away. But it still does not correctly remove the Schedule I want to remove.**

So what am I doing wrong? I've done a lot of googling. [Found bugs in Hibernate 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204252/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-and-orphanremoval-cascade) which do not apply to me since i'm using 3.6.7. [Found that hashcode and equals have to be implemented correctly and found that JPA and Hibernate annotations often clash with each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14457716/hibernate-3-6-10-doesnt-cascade-delete-through-onetomany-jointable). I've also found that bi-directional relations have problems with cascading, but again it does not apply to me. But aside from all those searches, I haven't quite found a solution for this one. Or perhaps I'm overlooking something.

Please help me out and thank you!

Comment: it does not, it's unidirectional as it says in the title

Comment: There seems to be some suggestions out there that you need to call `merge()` and not `saveOrUpdate()`.  That doesn't make sense to me but it's worth a shot.  In addition, you might try removing the `@Cascade` annotation, it doesn't make sense to have that when you're using the cascade element in `@OneToMany`.  Finally, are you sure you're checking for removal after the transaction has been committed?

Comment: try this: remove the "cascade" attribute inside the `@OneToMany` annotation and keep the `@Cascade` one. Besides, OrphanRemoval is about remove the children when the parent is deleted, this is not what you're trying to do.

Comment: I tried using just one cascade annotation and nothing worked. I will try the merge I guess.

Comment: merge did work, thanks! It worked even with both annotations on the set definition.

Comment: @Pace please put the merge thing as an answer so I can mark it as one. And thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason `saveOrUpdate()` doesn't properly process delete-orphans.  You have to call `merge()` instead.